# How to run several shortcuts (.lnk files) with a script in Windows?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, wsh

I’m trying to create a script to run all the tools I use working in a particular project (dor instance, gulp, phpstorm, php server, etc.)

I’d like to run shortcuts but not executable files. I can see two possible ways to achieve it in Windows:

1. VbScript
2. cmd.exe

Unfortunately, I’ve failed both:

**1)    WshShell fire .lnk file and I can't find an alternative way to do that:**

To do so I’m trying to write .cmd file or .vbs
However, I’ve got the problem in each way.

```
Dim WshShell

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "notepad.exe" ' Works alright
WshShell.Run "C:\Users\eugene\Desktop\gulp EngMe.lnk" ' got an Exception: Unknown Exception
```

**2)    .cmd script waits for closing previously started app:**

```
@rem urls and filesystem shortcuts start alright:
"C:\Users\eugene\Desktop\8000.url"
"C:\Users\eugene\Desktop\project_folder.lnk"

@rem the following two commands are starting sequentially, when the previous one has closed.
"notepad.exe"
@rem shortcut to %windir%\system32\notepad.exe:
"C:\Users\eugene\Desktop\Notepad_.lnk"
```

What I'm doing wrong and is there another way to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paths with spaces must be `"quoted"` when fed to `.Run` so:

```
WshShell.Run """C:\Users\eugene\Desktop\gulp EngMe.lnk"""
```

Will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try using powershell for scripting.

Look at the question -  [Execute shortcuts like programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524/execute-shortcuts-like-programs)

Look at Mark Schill's answer using invoke-item to launch .lnk files like programs.

This is probably your best way to address your script challenges.

Comment: Thanks so much! I haven't known about powershell yet. I've tried and invoke-item works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [shortcutjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat) which is capable to read a .lnk file properties. With this you will execute all `.lnk` files in the current directory in the correct working directory:

```
@echo off

for %%# in (*.lnk) do (
    call :executeShortcut "%%#"
)

exit /b %errorlevel%
:executeShortcut - %1 - shortcut to execute
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('call shortcutjs.bat -examine %1') do (
    if /i "%%a" equ "Target" (
        set "target=%%b"
        set "target=!target:~1!"
    )

    if /i "%%a" equ "Working Directory" (
        set "workdir=%%b"       
        set "workdir=!workdir:~1!"
    )
)

start "%target%" /d "%workdir%" /wait /b "%target%"
exit /b %errorlevel%
```