# Run all shortcut in the mother path of VBScript

Tags: vbscript, shortcut, shortcut-file

I want to have a executable VBS that run all windows shortcut in the current folder of my VBS.
My shortcuts are both Excel and PDF.
I've made this code, but i have an error on "WshShell.Run objFile.Path"
Other line look working correctly

```
Dim FSO
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
GetCurrentFolder = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(GetCurrentFolder)
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
   If LCase(Right(objFile.Path, 4)) = ".lnk" Then
      WshShell.Run objFile.Path
   End If
Next
```

I want the mother path adapt to VBS, so i can copy past VBS and put it in other folders
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to spaces in one or more of your file paths. Correct this by placing quotes around the path: `WshShell.Run """" & objFile.Path & """"`

The posted script is running all shortcuts in the *current* directory, which is not necessarily the *script's* directory (e.g. if the script is launched via the command line from another folder). To fix that, use: `FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)`.

Here is the complete, corrected, script:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
GetCurrentFolder = FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(GetCurrentFolder)
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
   If LCase(Right(objFile.Path, 4)) = ".lnk" Then
      WshShell.Run """" & objFile.Path & """"
      WScript.Sleep 1000 'adjust as needed 
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Just like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36599265/692942) from 6 years ago.

Comment: @user692942 I had actually flagged it with that duplicate, but then I noticed the OP's other issue is the current directory versus the script's directory. And yes, there's a duplicate for that too, but then which duplicate to pick?

Comment: I know what you mean but questions that have multiple issues aren’t focused on one problem which again is a flaggable reason in itself. The main issue I would say though is the lack of double quotes which we see three or four times a week.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the code. I tested with heavy Excel and it open only 1 shortcut. I fix the problem by adding "WScript.Sleep 4000" so it let the time to open my file between each loops